# Add array of string to database in Hibernate

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm beginner in Hibernate framework, and now I integrated Spring and Hibernate in one project.
I ran it OK, but it have something I can't understand why. The problem is:

I have bean class decribed here :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sample")
public class Sample {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String sex;
    private String[] interests;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "firstName")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Column(name = "lastName")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

@Column(name = "sex")
public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setInterests(String[] interests) {
    this.interests = interests;
}

@Column(name = "interests")
public String[] getInterests() {
    return interests;
}
}
```

In this class, you see, I have interests field is array of string which showed as many of checkbox.

In DAO, when controller call to save object to database, I just use `hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(sample)` class in Spring to persist object.

If database use default charset, it's OK, run and don't have any error but when I select table in database system, it show me a unreadable string, it's similar to `¬í ur [Ljava.lang.String;­ÒVçé{G  xp   t    Quidditcht  Herbology` . I think it's 'place holder' which Hibernate gave to split when I want to read and fill back in object.

But the problem is if database system use utf8 charset, it can't run, and throw exception similar to `Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05ur...' for column 'interests' at row 1`

I think because that string is not supported in database with utf8 charset.

Any idea about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is trying to persist the result of calling toString on the interests array.

You need to either set up you getInterests to return a formatted string or map to a different table as a onetomany relationship. As you probably want to populate interests from DB I would recommend the second option (I have annoate do fields, but you can easily change this to use getters, in fact I shoul dprobabbly annoated my getters) :

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sample", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
    private List<Interests> interests;
```

And interests could be like this

```
 @Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 256)
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Sample sample;
```

Comment: As you said, I persist the result of calling toString on the interests array, why can Hibernate read it clearly when I read it back, although it a unreadable string?

And if I change getInterests to return a formatted string, can Hibernate read it back? Need I change setInterests and split, too?

Comment: Now I changed `public String getInterests() {//code here}`, and I receive a error message, you know, because properties is array, the return of get method need to be a array of string.

Comment: "why can Hibernate read it clearly when I read it back, although it a unreadable string?" that doesn;t make sense. Hibernate will read it back as one string, thats why i suggest the second option. But I recommned you get a full undestanding of toString and general java OOP before starting hibernate.

Comment: I just want to save it as normal string, which I can split it by use space token to get array of strings. So, thanks for your reply!

Comment: Does it have any way which just use String class and don't need to use other entity?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked you code  and i think in "`interests`" field you want to store any values from array and same while retrieving from the DB.
You need to use `enum` kind of functionality but dont know whether your DB is supporting or not ?
I have the same functionality in one of my project and we have used DB `enum` in database, it is PostgreSQL.
If your db is not supporting the `enum` then you have to use `OneToMany` and have to create separate  table for Interest for mapping.

Comment: Thanks! I use some database system which is up to user choices. I need to think about right way.