# Call toString method when persist ArrayList?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a question about how to Hibernate save arraylist of string(or object). [I read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033833/1492882), so they said Hibernate will try call to toString method of arraylist to persist it.

I wrote a small code for test that, but it's not working like what they said.

```
class CustomizeArrayList extends ArrayList<String> 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("To String of customize arraylist");
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

I'm using this type as so:

```
@Column("array")
private CustomizrArrayList array
```

It's not calling toString method, is it using reflection to persist or serialization rather or anything else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I read somewhere" is never a good starting point. Please reference the exact article.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16033833/1492882. Here is a reference link.

Comment: In that question, they talk about **arrays**, not **lists**. Hibernate knows how to handle lists.

Comment: ... and that's why it's always worth including the reference.

Comment: How did you configure Hibernate for this type? Show us the XML mapping, please or the Java annotations that you used.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla : I tested for persist ArrayList object and pure array object, it's the same value in database. I just want to use ArrayList of string, `@Column(name = "array")` is all. Persist array use one to many or many to many is OK now.

Comment: And how do you want to have it persisted in the database - one row per String of the List, or one column containing all strings concatenated by a separation character?

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you use this type in your code (along with all JPA annotations, please)

Comment: @Johanna I'm testing for save array of string in one row by separation character. But I just want to understand how to hibernate save arraylist.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla : As I said, I'm just use customize array list as properties of class. ‛@Column("array") private CustomizrArrayList array‛ .

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate knows many internal Java types and how to convert them. The `List` type is one of them. For all list types (linked, array based or your custom one), Hibernate will use the same list-based approach which basically tries to put all elements of the list into another table.

You don't want that. One way to achieve what you want is to use `String[]` (i.e. a basic array type instead of a collection) instead of your custom type but that would create new problems elsewhere.

The correct solution is to tell Hibernate that you need special handling of this type. Implement the interface `UserType` ([docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom-ut)). In the methods `nullSafeGet()` and `nullSafeSet()`, you can convert between the DB column (`VARCHAR`, I guess) and your `CustomizeArrayList`.

To register the type, you can use the "Type Registry" ([see here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-registry)) or the `@Type` annotation ([blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/annotating-custom-types))

Comment: Thanks for reply, but if I save a `String[]` or `ArrayList`, Hibernate will append a strange string to my record in the table, it's hex string and similar to memory address of computer, it make me thing it call to toString method.

Comment: Note that Hibernate usually wraps your class in a proxy, so it might not call the `toString()` that you expect. Also, how do you plan to read the value from the database? There is no "fromString()" method...